# Include a different picture on title slide than on other slides in powerdot template

Tags: templates, powerdot

I am writing a powerdot template and would like to include a picture on the title slide that does not appear on any other slide. On other slides I want to include a different picture.

Working from the [`powerdot-default.sty`](http://emis.mi.sanu.ac.rs/zmath/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/powerdot/powerdot-default.sty) file I have included a picture using the command

```
\newbox\pd@imagebox
\pdifsetup{landscape}{%
  \sbox\pd@imagebox{\includegraphics[
    width=\slidewidth,height=\slideheight]{a.eps}%
  }%
}
```

I'd now like to include am image on the title slide that is different to the above - anyone know how to do this? I've found this question asked before but no clear answer as to how, apologies if this should be straightforward but I've been playing with this for a while and getting nowhere.

Comment: Without a compilable minimal example it's impossible to help.

Answer (score 1):

This command actually puts an image on the slide

```
\includegraphics[width=\slidewidth, height=\slideheight]{your_image.eps}
```

You can use it, basically, everywhere. If you want your title slide to have different style (provided that you defined a template for other slides) then you can use `emptyslide` environment and `includegraphics` :

```
\begin{emptyslide}{title}
\includegraphics{your_image.eps}
\end{emptyslide}
```

Comment: Dmitry - I tried including that command in the template, however it just leads to errors.  I need to change the style file for the slide template to include the image - not insert the image in my presentation.

Answer (score 0):

This made me crazy for 3 days. I finally found a way I find satisfactory.

I use the logo option inside the options of the maketitle command.

```
\maketitle[logohook=t,
logopos={.5\slidewidth,\slideheight},
logocmd={\includegraphics[height=.32\slideheight]{image.eps}}]
```

It shows my image.eps only in the title slide. The only drawback is that you have to position the logo with heght and locopos by trial-error procedure. But it works, and it makes me so happy. Hope this helps !